# Formatting when using add-content in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to consolidate all of the text files in a folder into one csv file with the name of each text file above its content in the new file. I would like it to come out like this (in the text files before consolidation, the text appears in a list as below, so I'd like the text to appear in the csv file in the same fashion that it exists in the text files):

**textfile1.txt**

```
-content content

-content content

-content content
```

**textfile2.txt:**

```
-content content

-content content

-content content
```

**textfile3.txt:**

```
-content content

-content content

-content content
```

However it is currently coming out like this:

**textfile1.txt:**

```
content content content content content content
```

**textfile2.txt:**

```
content content content content content content
```

**textfile3.txt:**

```
content content content content content content
```

My code is this:

```
dir "C:\text files\*.*" | ForEach {
$variable = "$($_.Name)`n$(Get-content $_.FullName)" |Add-Content
"C:\text files\output\output.csv"}
```

If anyone can help me to format the `Add-Content` so it doesn't group the whole file into one string, I would be most thankful!

Comment: If you have a line with a filename and then subsequent lines with data, that would not really be CSV format. I'm not really clear on what your goal is.

Comment: Are the leading `-` in your example `-content content` intentional?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of what the output should look like, and perhaps differentiate the `content` 's so we know what should go where?

Answer (score 1):

you again!

This is actually a very easy fix.  We grab the file name and add it to the file, then grab the file contents and add them as well, so the total code looks like this:

```
dir "C:\text files\*.*" | ForEach {
  Add-Content -value $_.Name -Path .\Output.txt
  Get-Content  $_.FullName | Add-Content -Path .\Output.txt
}
```

The results?

```
TextFile1.txt
-content content

-content content

-content content
TextFile2.txt
-content content

-content content

-content content
TextFile3.txt
-content content

-content content

-content content
```

Now, what if you wanted to add a some comments or make it obvious where the new file begins?  We just change the Add-Content line on line 2, to something like this `Add-Content -value "---FileName: $($_.Name)------" -Path .\Output.txt`, giving us an output like this:

```
---FileName: TextFile1.txt------
-content content

-content content
```

Comment: 1RedOne - You are my favourite person on here. Thanks again for saving my bacon,